# Why is this map surjective??

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, quaternions

I have the following Lie group homomorphism:

$\phi: Sp(1) \rightarrow SO(3)$ given by $\phi(q)x=qxq^{-1}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $Sp(1)$ is the set of quaternions with module $1$.

I want to prove it is surjective, i.e., every matrix in $SO(3)$ comes by $\phi$ from an element $q \in Sp(1)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: Also, it is not immediately obvious how the multiplication $qxq^{-1}$ is defined. You really should make that clear in your post.

Comment: What do you know?

Comment: Every element of ${\rm SO}(3)$ is rotation around an axis by an angle. And $qxq^{-1}$ (where $q=\exp(\theta{\bf u})$) is rotation by $2\theta$ around the axis $\bf u$.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to see that your map $\phi(q)x=qxq^{-1}$ is actually a linear isometry and orientation preserving. The quaternion $qxq^{-1}$ has real part $0$ for any quaternion $q$ with modulus $1$. Now the point is the map $\phi$ sends $q$ and $-q$ to the same rotation of $\mathbb{R^3}$. The following document has the formula for a rotation matrix associated to a unit quaternion, which I will not attempt to derive here....[Rotation Matrix](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/geombchap8.pdf) (incidentally that document says the expression for this matrix in $SO(3)$ is due to Euler...)